# timer function with global variable not counting down

Tags: python, tkinter

so I am made a function that counts down, I have it count down from number n minus 1, it works but if I add a global variable (I named it flag, if flag == True then I want it to count down. if flag == False the I want timer to stop, I need that this variable to be global b/c I have another button that changes flag to False if pressed called pause. however my function does not display 5 , 4, 3, 2,1 every second. it just displays 5 now, when I add the global variables. and it only happens if I added global variables. please tell me what need to change. I am open to the idea of changing the way, I pause and play this function, if there is a different way to do so.

```
flag = True
holder_for_time = 6
# timer for next ball
def update_timer_countdown(n):  
    global flag
    if flag == True and n != "1":
        n = int(n)
        n -= 1
        n = str(n)
        timer.config(
            text="Next draw in:" + n + "s", padx=5, pady=45, font=("Helvetica", 17)
        )
        return timer.after(1000, update_timer_countdown, 6) # this step does not come through
    elif flag == True and n == "1":
        return update_timer_countdown(6)
    elif flag == False:
        global holder_for_time
        holder_for_time = n


timer = Label(root, text="Next draw in:" + "s", padx=5, pady=45, font=("Helvetica", 17))
timer.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=5, sticky="nsew")
update_timer_countdown(6)
```

Comment: you never update flag, it will always be true.

Comment: I have a different function that changes flag, that function works but the countdown one does not

Comment: `return timer.after(1000, update_timer_countdown, 6)` - Not passing the value `n` here to the function.

Comment: yes that makes sense I an constantly passing in 6 which constantly returns 5 thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have edit few lines of code, and now it works how you want
here is the code

```
from tkinter import *

flag = True
holder_for_time = 6
n = 6


# timer for next ball
def update_timer_countdown():
    global flag, n
    if flag:
        if n != 0:
            n -= 1
            timer.config(
                text=f"Next draw in: {n}s", padx=5, pady=45, font=("Helvetica", 17)
            )
            return timer.after(1000, update_timer_countdown)  # this step does not come through

    else:
        global holder_for_time
        holder_for_time = n


def _command():
    global flag
    flag = not flag
    if flag:
        pause['text'] = "pause"
    else:
        pause['text'] = "resume"
    update_timer_countdown()


def restart_command():
    global flag, n
    flag = True
    n = 6
    update_timer_countdown()


root = Tk()
timer = Label(root, text="Next draw in:", padx=5, pady=45, font=("Helvetica", 17))
timer.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=5, sticky="nsew")
update_timer_countdown()
pause = Button(root, text="pause", font=("Helvetica", 10), command=_command)
pause.grid(row=0, column=0)
restart = Button(root, text="Restart", font=("Helvetica", 10), command=restart_command)
restart.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).